# CustomImages on TextInput area of ThirdParty chating Applications in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I Had send some images from customKeyboard using UIClipBoard, after pasting Image, it Shows like  this [Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brcgn.png) ,
means text is not continuing after image

But I need Like this [Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omA7U.png)

Is it Possible to set like "**Text and Image and then Text**" in sameLine. if yes please give me some guidance how to do this.